# send multiple messages using telegraf (nodejs) - by order

Tags: node.js, typescript, recursion, promise, telegraf.js

I am using telegraf (nodejs) to build a telegram bot that sends data by request.
And i want to reply to the user messages with media (photos/videos) and texts in sequentially order.
inerder to do so im collecting all the required data in promises array, and i want to send it in specific order (from id 0 to n).

I tried to use recursion to resolve the promises by order, and still the messages didnt arrive in the currect order..
The texts always arrive first than the media arrive.
this is the recursion:

```
  const promiseResolver = async (
    promises: Array<Promise<any>>,
    index = 0
  ): Promise<void> => {
    if (index >= promises.length) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    await promises[index].then(() => {
      return promiseResolver(promises, index + 1);
    });
  };
```

i have an array of n promises to resolve.
im using the methods from telegraf: replyWithMediaGroup(), reply()
how can i insure that the promises will get resolve and only then continue to to resolve the next promise ?

Comment: Did you manage to send the replies in the desired order? thanks